# iOS SearchBar and SeachDisplayController misplacement

Tags: ios, objective-c, searchbar, hamburger-menu

I need to use a searchbar but I use this code :

```
self.searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
_searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44);
_searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
_searchBar.placeholder = @"Search stores";
_searchBar.delegate = self;

self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
_searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
_searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
_searchController.delegate = self;

self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

and the result is this... I lost my hamburgare menu button and I cant change the width of the searchbar. I also have a strange gap and it seeems to be as big as my navbar. How can I get back the hamburger menu button and fix the strange gap?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put following code into ViewDidLoad. It will work for iOS 7+

```
 if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"6.1")) {
       self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
  }
```

**Edited**

```
 - (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setActive:visible animated:animated];

    [self.searchContentsController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: NO animated: NO];

    CGRect frame = self.searchResultsTableView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(self.searchContentsController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame);

    frame.size.height = CGRectGetHeight(frame) - CGRectGetMinY(frame);

    self.searchResultsTableView.frame = frame;

    frame = self.searchBar.frame;
    self.searchBar.frame = frame;

    [self.searchContentsController.view insertSubview:self.searchBar aboveSubview:self.searchResultsTableView];

}
```

**One More Try to Implement this solution.**

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Note : UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8. [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/)

Use following code support in iOS8

```
searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Also you can download [the sample code from here](https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController).

Comment: are you using `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @CsabiVidó I Update my answer please go thru that.

Comment: the last one would be much better! but i have to support iOS 7+